# Extreme High Quality HDR livestreaming using FFMPEG/SRT with hevc_nvenc

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, hdr, nvenc

So I am working out and just testing different encoder settings and I wonder if someone has some insights , it works OK now but maybe I can improve stuff.

first lets start with my whole command, lets ignore the audio part for now:

The final input will be from bm decklink so i just put some testfile in there for now.
Using a RTX3090

```
-pix_fmt p016le -tier high -c:v hevc_nvenc -rc:v vbr -cq 19 -qmin 10 -qmax 99 -b:v 25M -g 24 -maxrate:v 50M -bf 0 -b_ref_mode 0 -weighted_pred 1 -rc-lookahead 75 -spatial-aq 1 -aq-strength 8 -temporal-aq 1 -profile:v main10 -color_primaries bt2020 -color_trc smpte2084 -colorspace bt2020nc -preset p5 -tune ll -f mpegts srt://URL:PORT?pkt_size=1316
```

Lets dissect to give you an idea of my though process here:

`-pix_fmt p016le`   This sets 10bit 4:4:4 YUV  which is what I want

`-tier high`        sounds fancy, no idea what this does.

`-c:v hevc_nvenc`   use hevc_nvenc

`-rc:v vbr -cq 28 -qmin 1 -qmax 99`
Variable BitRate Encoding with  a constant quality factor of 28 (lower = better quality) then some qmin and qmax just to be able to vary it for testing.

`-b:v 10M -g 24 -maxrate:v 25M` Taget bitrate for vbr = 10Mbit with a peak of 25Mbit

`-bf 0 -b_ref_mode 0`  Turns off B-Frames, I dont think I want those in a stream? do I? ehhh need to test this further

`-weighted_pred 1 -rc-lookahead 75 -spatial-aq 1 -aq-strength 8 -temporal-aq 1`
Super fancy nvidia tech that I turned on probably have something stupid in here.

`-profile:v main10` 10bit profile

`-color_primaries bt2020 -color_trc smpte2084 -colorspace bt2020nc`
The HDR part.

`-preset p5 -tune ll`
P5 quality encoding setting "slow" seems fine for UHD input on a 3090 but its hitting 80% all of the time, Tune LowLatency as .. its a livestream

`-f mpegts srt://URL:PORT?pkt_size=1316`
throw it into a mpegts stream and send to my srt endpoint.

All in all the dencoder right now seems to struggle sometimes seemilgy randomly so its not perfectly tuned *yet*

if you have great ideas I would love to hear your input!